# AWS CloudFront blocks Set-Cookie header

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CDK to construct a `CloudFront distribution` which has a `Lambda Function` behind an `HTTP API Gateway` as default origin. I am hosting a web application from this lambda which needs to set and receive cookie but CloudFront seems to be blocking the `Set-Cookie` header from making it to the browser.

I was unsure if CloudFront or API Gateway was blocking the header so I requested the lambda directly from the API Gateway URL and then the `Set-Cookie` header is included in the response.

I tried to follow the suggestion from a bunch of other threads and created a custom cache policy that had cookies set to `ALL` but this did not work. I'm not sure if it's just me but all of the information on this topic seems very convoluted and like black magic.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me the concrete things I need to configure in my CloudFront distribution to make it pass the `Set-Cookie` header from the origin to the requester and the `Cookie` header from the requester to the origin.

Thank you in advance!